# Is it possible to ensure a User's input doesn't exceed a specific range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I currently have a set up where there are input boxes that take numbers. The range is 0-100. I want to keep the value within that range, so if it's set to like, 200, it just caps at 100, or 0 in the case of a negative number.

I figure it'd be possible with an if statement. But the only way I see it working is through multiple `if`/`else if` statements. So I'm wondering if there's some other method to accomplish the goal.

[Can view the current thing here](https://codepen.io/Slateboard/pen/PoNjrbr)

My code:

```js
function updateStats() {
  var hp = document.getElementById("hpValue").value;
  var mp = document.getElementById("mpValue").value;
  var strength = document.getElementById("strengthValue").value;
  var defense = document.getElementById("defenseValue").value;
  var speed = document.getElementById("speedValue").value;
  var luck = document.getElementById("luckValue").value;

  document.getElementById("hpBar").style.width = hp + "%";
  document.getElementById("mpBar").style.width = mp + "%";
  document.getElementById("strBar").style.width = strength + "%";
  document.getElementById("defBar").style.width = defense + "%";
  document.getElementById("speedBar").style.width = speed + "%";
  document.getElementById("luckBar").style.width = luck + "%";

}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.statbarsBG {
  background-color: #808080;
  text-align: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Set the progressbar to relative */
  position: relative;
}

.statbarsHP {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}

.statbarsMP {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 20px;
}

.statbarsSTR {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.statbarsDEF {
  background-color: darkblue;
  height: 20px;
}

.statbarsSPD {
  background-color: powderblue;
  height: 20px;
}

.statbarsLUCK {
  background-color: khaki;
  height: 20px;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Character Rank: B</h3>

<table cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <th>Stat</th>
    <th> Level</th>
    <th> Value (Between 0-100)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>HP</td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsHP" style=" width:93%" id="hpBar" </div>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="hpValue"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td label="MP">MP</td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsMP" style=" width:30%" id="mpBar">

        </div>
      </div>
      </>
    </td>

    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="mpValue" value=""> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>STR </td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsSTR" style=" width:75%" id="strBar" </div>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="strengthValue" value=""> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>DEF </td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsDEF" style=" width:89%" id="defBar" </div>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="defenseValue"> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>SPEED </td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsSPD" style=" width:45%" id="speedBar" </div>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="speedValue" value=""> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>LUCK </td>
    <td>
      <div class="statbarsBG">
        <div class="statbarsLUCK" style=" width:95%" id="luckBar" </div>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="luckValue" value="" class="userInput"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="updateStats()">Click to Update Stats</button>
```

Comment: Try: Math.max(Math.min(value, 100), 0)

Comment: Can you use an input with max length attribute ? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0" max="100" />` - this won't stop the user from typing whatever they want, but it does give you access to built-in Validity checking, making it as simple as `if( inputElement.validity.valid) { ... }`

Comment: A side note, just in case. While Javascript is OK for guiding user to correct values,  your receiving server side script can't rely on Javascript checks and will need to retest values after submittal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up a lot of that repetition.

```
const map = {
    hpValue: 'hpBar',
    mpValue: 'mpBar',
    strengthValue: 'strBar',
    defenseValue: 'defBar',
    speedValue: 'speedBar',
    luckValue: 'luckBar'
};
for (let fieldId in map)
    document.getElementById(map[fieldId]).style.width = document.getElementById(fieldId).value+'%';
```

Now, outside the function, we can listen for the `input` event and act accordingly.

```
document.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    if (!evt.target.matches('table input')) return;
    let intVal = parseInt(evt.target.value);
    if (isNaN(intVal)) return evt.target.value = '';
    if (intVal < 0) return evt.target.value = 0;
    if (intVal > 100) return evt.target.value = 100;
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/mitya33/pen/zYqMYNK).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It also looks a whole lot nicer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not super on board with the idea of `return evt.target.value = 0` in an event handler, I feel like that may come a bit too close to `return false;` which may cancel the event...

Answer (score 4):

Use `<input type="number">`. And to set the range you can use the attributes `min` and `max`.

So for example:

`<input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="strengthValue" value="">`

To prevent users from typing in a value higher than the max or lower than the min you can use this script:

```
function checkMinMax(event) {
var value = this.value,
    min = this.getAttribute('min'),
    max = this.getAttribute('max');

if(value < min)
    this.value = min;
else if(value > max)
    this.value = max;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('yourinput').addEventListener('keyup', checkMinMax);
});
```

Comment: This will prevent the user from typing in a value outside of the min/max?

Comment: @Slateboard Edited for you with the prevention of typing a value outside of min/max

Answer (score 0):

use below code for multiple input box validation (min value and max value):

Example:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" onkeyup="myFunction(event, 0, 100)">

<input type="number" min="100" max="200" onkeyup="myFunction(event, 100, 200)">

<script>
    function myFunction(e, minValue, maxValue){
        let number = e.target.value;
        if(number > maxValue){
            // check if number is greater than max value
            e.target.value = maxValue;
        }else if(number < minValue){
            //check if number is less than min value
            e.target.value = minValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regular expression to test if the value entered is a number between 0 and 100.

```
if (document.getElementById("hpValue").value.match(/^(\d{1,2}|100)$/)){
  // value was a number between 0 and 100
}
```

You could create a resusable function to test the value:

```
function isValidRange(inputValue){
   return inputValue.match(/^(\d{1,2}|100)$/);
}

// usage:
if(isValidRange(document.getElementById("hpValue").value)){
   // value was a number between 0 and 100
}
```

Comment: if you are going for regex, why not use the pattern attrbute? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: regex checks are one of the last things to do client side, as they are frequently much slower, and don't make  sense for such trivial comparisons as in this case.

Comment: I don't think the user of a page is going to notice a difference of a few milliseconds between the use of a regex or not and is certainly not a reason to down vote this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using input type='number' as evilgenious448 points out is a good hint, but ineffective as you can insert a bigger value by keyboard.

You can use Jquery library.

First, add a common class to all inputs, i.e. `class = "inpt"`

Then, retrieve all the input fields at once and apply if statements.

```
$(document).on("change", ".inpt", function() {
    $(".inpt").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() > 100) $(this).val(100);
        if ($(this).val() < 0) $(this).val(0);
    });
});
```